# viewDidAppear equivalent in app delegate

Tags: objective-c

I want to check orientation of app in the app delegate, is there a viewDidAppear equivalent in the app delegate?

Or where should I place the code to check where the orientation has changed (in the app delegate)

Answer (score 1):

Well you have `applicationDidFinishLoading:withOptions:` which is your closest thing to a `viewDidLoad`, but it only runs once when the application first launches and that's it.

If you want to monitor the device orientation outside of a view controller, your best bet it to use the notification center, and register your class as an observer. Something like this should do the trick

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  
                                           object:nil];
```

Then whenever the orientation is changed, the `orientationChanged:` method will be called.
Just make sure that you unsubscribe when the class is destroyed or deallocated with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: i tried this it doesnt seem to detect change? I am also using `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;`
                                                                           
    `if(orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)||orientation==(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown))` etc

Comment: Im suing this in the orientation changed method as you prescribed

Comment: hm strange. And that method isn't being called at all?

Comment: If you're just wanting to use this in the app delegate, you can try using the `application:willChangeStatusBarOrientation:duration:` and `application:didChangeStatusBarOrientation:` methods which are part of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol

Comment: The method is only being called once and its not detecting landscape (could be a problem with my code)

Comment: It shouldn't be your code stopping it. have you tried those delegate methods?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34481/discussion-between-user2515907-and-pareeohnos)